# JavaScript detect if giving region and date is a holiday

Tags: javascript

```
const regions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Baden-Württemberg",
    holidays: HOLIDAYS_BW,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bayern",
    holidays: HOLIDAYS_BY,
  },
]

const HOLIDAYS_BW = [
  { date: "01.01.2022", day: "Samstag" },
  { date: "06.01.2022", day: "Donnerstag" },
];

const HOLIDAYS_BY = [
  { date: "01.01.2022", day: "Samstag" },
  { date: "06.01.2022", day: "Donnerstag" },
];
```

How can I check wether the region and date the user picks is a holiday.

For instance I would like to check wether the region Bayern and the date 05.05.2022 is a holiday, the array shows all holidays

I tried this so far, but it does not seems to work

```
regions.find((region) => region.holidays.includes(date));
```

The date which I gave to the "query" is in this format

```
 Tue Mar 22 2022 01:00:00 GMT+0100
```

That is an issue I think

Comment: What are the inputs and the outputs? You get the region name (string) and a date (string) and you want true/false if it's holiday? It's not clear

Comment: @Balastrong I want to basically check if it is a holiday, using that bool I can continue further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like so, finding if the region exists first (returns `undefined` if not), and then if the date is in the list.

```js
return regions.find(r => r.name == region)?.holidays.some(h => h.date == date)
```

If you don't like the `undefined` and always want false, just add `?? false` at the end.

```js
return regions.find(r => r.name == region)?.holidays.some(h => h.date == date) ?? false
```

```js
const HOLIDAYS_BW = [{
    date: "01.01.2022",
    day: "Samstag"
  },
  {
    date: "06.01.2022",
    day: "Donnerstag"
  },
];

const HOLIDAYS_BY = [{
    date: "01.01.2022",
    day: "Samstag"
  },
  {
    date: "06.01.2022",
    day: "Donnerstag"
  },
];

const regions = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Baden-Württemberg",
    holidays: HOLIDAYS_BW,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bayern",
    holidays: HOLIDAYS_BY,
  },
]

function formatDate(date) {
  return `${('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2)}.${('0' + (date.getMonth())).slice(-2)}.${date.getFullYear()}`
}

function isHoliday(region, date) {
  var formattedDate = formatDate(date);
  return regions.find(r => r.name == region)?.holidays.some(h => h.date == formattedDate);
}

console.log(isHoliday('Bayern', new Date(2022, 01, 06))); // true
console.log(isHoliday('Baden-Württemberg', new Date(2022, 01, 01))); // true
console.log(isHoliday('Bayern', new Date())); // false
console.log(isHoliday('Hamburg', new Date(2022, 01, 06))); // undefined as Hamburg is not on the list
```

### UPDATE

Turns out the input is a date, you can format it first with something like:

```js
var formattedDate = `${('0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2)}.${('0' + (date.getMonth())).slice(-2)}.${date.getFullYear()}`
```

and then use the string for the comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the question, I pass a javascript date string which is an issue. Do you have any solution for that?=

Comment: I updated the answer. In short, you can convert the date before doing the comparison and it still works :)